# Python CAPTCHA-like image disortion

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, captcha

I would like to disort some images the same way standard CAPTCHA disorts fonts. How would I achieve it in python? What libraries/algorithms I should use? Any proof-of-concept?

DISCLAIMER: I was googling for some time before I asked this question but I couldn't find any satisfying answer. I'm new to the field so I can't provide any code proving my 'research effort'...

Comment: Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart - CAPTCHA. If you want to distort images I would try a nonlinear remapping of your image data; obviously, some of the data points will get lost during the process. So the task would be to create an appropriate kernel? You could e.g. play around with some scalar fields as found in some physics examples. Is that what you want?

Comment: I'm a simple man. I don't understand your answer at all. I need some code that does the thing.

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans - than you for your extremely valuable input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for PyCaptcha http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/pycaptcha/

The actual code to distort is here: http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/pycaptcha/Captcha/Visual/Distortions.py

The work is done by PIL's transform function, like this:

```
image.transform(image.size, Image.MESH, mesh, self.filtering)
```

The rest of the code is there essentially to generate the mesh that is used.

Comment: OK, I think we are almost there. Now let's assume I have PIL image instance containing the actual image I would like to disort. What do I do? I can't find any entry point here, in Disortions.py there are three classes each of which contain render method accepting image. Should I create instance of each and pass my image through three 'render's?

Comment: Sorry, stupid question, I need to use SineWrap. I will give it a try and let know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

put simple: you have an image, which is a 2D array, each array element represents a pixel. Distorting an image means, that you put some pixel value also to neighboring places where it has not been before.

To give you something like an example, I modified an example from the `matplotlib`; I relocate the regular x/y to an irregular spacing, thus, distorting the image. For captcha looks, you have to come up with some more creative remapping than I did.
More professional would obviously be to just remap the values to the array to keep the regular spaced data.

So some fun is still left for you to play around (; Hope this helped you out as a starter.

```
import pylab as P
import numpy as N

# http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields
# /pcolormesh_levels.html
dx, dy = 0.05, 0.05
y, x = N.mgrid[slice(1, 5 + dy, dy),
                slice(1, 5 + dx, dx)]
z = N.sin(x) ** 10 + N.cos(10 + y * x) * N.cos(x)

#distort from regular pixels to something else...
x1 = N.exp(x)  
y1 = N.sqrt(y)

P.figure()
P.pcolormesh(x,y,z)
P.figure()
P.pcolormesh(x1,y1,z)
P.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Distorting an image means shuffling of an pixel with any of its neighbouring pixel.

If algorithm shuffle a far pixel, distortion is high, and if a nearby pixel is shuffled distortion is low

I had worked on a similar problem few days ago, I've used PIL for this.

```
import math
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('image.jpg')  #open a image
width ,height = img.size
img_data = img.load()          #loading it, for fast operation
output = Image.new('RGB',img.size,"gray")  #New image for putput
output_img = output.load()    #loading this also, for fast operation

pix=[0, 0]
delta_x = 40     #you can lower the delta for high distortion
delta_y = 90     #or you can higher the delta for low distortion

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        #following expression calculates the snuffling 
        x_shift, y_shift =  ( int(abs(math.sin(x)*width/delta_x)) ,
                              int(abs(math.tan(math.sin(y)))*height/delta_y))

        #checking bounds
        if x + x_shift < width:
            pix[0] = x + x_shift
        else:
            pix[0] = x
        if y + y_shift < height :
            pix[1] = y + y_shift
        else:
            pix[1] = y

        # do the shuffling
        output_img[x,y] = img_data[tuple(pix)]
#Saving the image
output.save('output.jpeg')
```

The following expression is the key here, you can modify or create any similar expression by doing little mathematics, although this may also suit you as it is.

```
x_shift, y_shift =  ( int(abs(math.sin(x)*width/delta_x)) ,
                              int(abs(math.tan(math.sin(y)))*height/delta_y))
```

I have a sample:
Input image[image]
Output Image[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the code of [django-simple-captcha](https://raw.github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/master/captcha/views.py), there's a function `captcha_image` in https://raw.github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/master/captcha/views.py that you can adapt easily.