# How to generate such verification code samples？

Tags: machine-learning

I have a machine that I want to train it with verification codes which you can see at the following link.now the question is how can I generate this code?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqQAi.jpg

Comment: you mean the captcha code, or you need the algorithm for generating it?

Comment: I want to generate a lot of verification codes like this, but I don't know how to generate them, I need algorithms because I will use them for training.

Comment: ok, do you have any prefer language to generate your verification code?

Comment: I want to use Python.

Answer (score -1):

please follow the [link](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-generate-random-captcha-in-python/) structure to generate the codes, there is no limit for generating and you can make a quite good data set.
Also you can find similar question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091431/python-captcha-like-image-disortion).
at the second [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19149537/6927069) you can see the pyCaptcha which use by most of the python developers, I think it would be a better solution than first link.

Comment: That's very kind of you.